# javascript missing statement woes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate a form based on values provided, I've written the script but it says missing; before statement

Here's my code if anyone can see the error please help point it out.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function calc(theForm) {
       var myEquip1 = document.Edit.EQup1.value;
       var myEquip2 = document.Edit.EQup2.value;
       Var myFixedPrice = document.Edit.InitialPrice.value;
       Var myEquip1Price = document.Edit.EQup1Price.value;
       Var myEquip2Price = document.Edit.EQup2Price.value;

     if  (myEquip1 > 1)
     {
    var myEquip1Total = (myEquip1*myEquip1Price) - (myEquip1Price);
     }
else
 {
    var myEquip1Total = (myEquip1*myEquip1Price)-(myEquip1Price);
      }
     if  (myEquip2 > 1)
      {
    var myEquip2Total = (myEquip2*myEquip2Price)-(myEquip2Price);
      }
else
      {
    var myEquip2Total = (myEquip2*myEquip2Price)-(myEquip2Price);
}
    theForm.GrandTotal.value = (myEquip2Total+myEquip1Total+myFixedPrice)
    }
    </script>
```

The HTML is below i'm sure I've done something wrong but i can see it.

```
    <form name="Edit" method="post" action="mypageprocess">
<p><label for="EQup1">How many Branches?</label><br />
<select name="EQup1" onChange="calc(this.form)" id="EQup1"/>    
        <option value="0">Please select</option> 
        <option value="1" >One</option>
        <option value="2" >Two</option>
        <option value="3" >Three</option>
        <option value="4" >Four</option>
        <option value="5" >Five</option>
        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp; x <strong>$550.00</strong>
</p> 
<p><label for="EQup2">How many Satellits?</label><br />
<select name="EQup2" onChange="calc(this.form)" id="EQup2"/>    
        <option value="0">Please select</option> 
        <option value="1" >One</option>
        <option value="2" >Two</option>
        <option value="3" >Three</option>
        <option value="4" >Four</option>
        <option value="5" >Five</option>
        </select> &nbsp;&nbsp; x <strong>$440.00 </strong>
</p> 

<input type="text" onfocus="this.blur();" name="GrandTotal" size="10" readonly="readonly"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="InitialPrice" value="660" />
        <input type="hidden" name="EQup1Price" value="550" />
        <input type="hidden" name="EQup2Price" value="440" />
    </form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Note that the JavaScript errors will show up in your JS console.

Comment: How can i load the InitialPrice when the page loads so the box is not empty

Comment: Fill it in a DOM ready function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. `Var` won't work, use `var`.

Comment: My summing is not working correctly it's lumping them all as one 600440550       
   theForm.GrandTotal.value = (myEquip2Total+myEquip1Total+myFixedPrice)

Comment: parseInt(myEquip2Total+myEquip1Total+myFixedPrice) i'm doing something wrong not just sure what it is

Answer (score 2):

Both of your `<select>` elements are being closed prematurely as if they have no inner content.

Comment: Just to reiterate, don't do `<select />`.